# Как сделать выполнение команды раз в сутки. discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, asyncio

Пытаюсь реализовать обновление статистики по решению задач на сервере раз в неделю, но loop не реагирует либо дает ошибку.

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

import config
import controls
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))



@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def test1():
    chanel = bot.get_channel(config.CHANNEL_NEWS_ID)
    await chanel.send('Тест')


@test1.before_loop
async def test2():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

test1.start()
bot.run(config.TOKEN, log_handler=handler)
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vavil\PycharmProjects\Work\Разное\discord_bot_2\main.py", line 439, in <module>
    test1.start()
  File "C:\Users\vavil\PycharmProjects\Work\virtialpy\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 398, in start
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\vavil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 360, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому что вы пытаетесь вызвать асинхронную функцию `test1.start()` вне цикла событий. Если вы хотите, чтобы каждые 10 секунд вызывалась функция `test1`, запустите её во время запуска бота:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    test1.start()
```